# Cobian Backup - Delete oldest backup before beginning current backup

Tags: backup

I use Cobian Backup 11 Gravity to backup our server and would like to maximize the number of backups I can hold on an external drive.

Currently I have it set up to do incremental backups every night and a full backup on Sunday night and keep a few copies on the drive.

On Sunday I see that Cobian is first performing the full back up and then deleting the oldest backup.  I would for Cobian to first delete oldest backup and then perform the full backup, this would allow for 1 additional backup to be stored.